# Laravel Form Model binding not showing data

Tags: laravel, model-binding

I am trying to build a site and I get to the point where I would like to exploit the Form model binding

I set in the boot method of the RouteServiceProvider the binding between 'material' and 'App\Material' class

This is the creation Form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'material', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
@include('admin_panel.partials.material_form',['submitButtonText' => 'Add'])
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the include file:

```
{!! Form::label('title','Title',array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-2')) !!}
{!! Form::text('title','',array('class' => 'form-control')) !!} 
{!! Form::label('published_at', 'Ready on:') !!}
{!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::label('file','Choose the material: ',array('class' => 'col-sm-2')) !!}
{!! Form::file('file') !!}
{!! Form::submit($submitButtonText, array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
```

The operation of creating the material and save it to the db works perfectly.

When i want to edit a material before calling the edit view in the edit method of the MaterialController I use dd($material) to check if it is the correct object. The attributes (title, published_at,...) in the object on the screen are the correct one, so I am sure that the object I am passing to the edit view is the right one.

When i call the Edit View I print {!! $material->title !!} before the Form and the string is correct. This is the Form:

```
{!! Form::model($material, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route'=>array('material.update', $material), 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!} 
@include('admin_panel.partials.material_form',['submitButtonText' => 'Update']); 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The problem is that i don't see anything in the fields of the form...

I don't know where I made a mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I made a stupid mistake.

In the Form::text (and I think also the other fields) of the include form I forced the second argument (the text displaying in the input text form to be empty instead of NULL, thus overriding the value of the bind model.

my mistake.